# How use MongoDB in AEM6.1?

Tags: mongodb, aem

I want to use Mongo DB for new work in AEM6.1. Could you please let me know step to use MondoDB with AEM6.1. if you have any document then please share. I gone below mentioned online document and followed mentioned step but that is not working.

http://cq-ops.tumblr.com/post/86895378084/how-to-run-aem-60-with-mongodb-26

Whem i am starting my mongodb then error is displaying "Error reading config file: No such file or directory
try 'mongod.exe --help' for more information" .

Regards,
Satish

Answer (score 0):

the error you have is connected with mongod start process options
on Windows you can specify

> mongod.exe -f fileName,

so mongod expects configuration file with file name

try to start just **mongod** and check if it works as config provided on link is standard one.

Btw don't forget to create directores for collection files

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. . I executed below command , but none of these working. 1) mongod.exe --config C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod.cfg
 2) mongod.exe -f C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod.cfg

Comment: apologies on mobile phone didn't saw full comment :(  come to chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104903/mongo-queries-issues it will be   better to discuss that issue